# dynamically adding check box and getting its checked unchecked value in android

Tags: android, checkbox

I am creating an android app where there are 20 checkboxes to be shown to user for multiple selection. I have programmed to display the checkbox dynamically but the problem is how to get the checked box value ? I have tried this code so far.

**my global variables are**

```
ArrayList<MyCheckBox> listOfCheckedItem;
private int CHECKBOX_POSITION;
```

**and for adding checkboxes I did something like this**

```
listOfCheckedItem = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfCheckedItem.add(new MyCheckBox(true, "One")); //(isChecked,text)
        listOfCheckedItem.add(new MyCheckBox(false, "Two"));
        listOfCheckedItem.add(new MyCheckBox(true, "Three"));
        listOfCheckedItem.add(new MyCheckBox(false, "four"));
        listOfCheckedItem.add(new MyCheckBox(false, "five"));

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfCheckedItem.size(); i++) {
            CHECKBOX_POSITION = i;
            MyCheckBox myCheckBox = listOfCheckedItem.get(i);
            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
            checkBox.setChecked(myCheckBox.getIsChecked());
            checkBox.setText(myCheckBox.getText());
            selectCategoryLayout.addView(checkBox, params);
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    listOfCheckedItem.get(CHECKBOX_POSITION).setIsChecked(isChecked);
                }
            });
        }
```

**And to get the check boxes value I did like this**

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfCheckedItem.size(); i++) {
            MyCheckBox mcb = listOfCheckedItem.get(i);
            builder.append("\nstatus: " + mcb.getText() + " is " + mcb.getIsChecked());
        }
        resultView.setText(builder.toString());
```

For the first time when I run app every checkboxes are shown correctly and when I click on button to get the check boxes (checked/unchecked) value it shows the correct result, But when I check/uncheck any one of the checkboxes and again click on the button to get the result only last checkbox value is changed. What I am missing I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Add a tag attribute to your dynamically generated checkbox. Then find the view by that tag.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved,
Instead of doing this

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    listOfCheckedItem.get(CHECKBOX_POSITION).setIsChecked(isChecked);// changed this line as below code
                }
            });
```

I did like this

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    myCheckBox.setIsChecked(isChecked);//I changed this line and every thing worked fine
                }
            });
```